# Using AxesOrigin in LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, code-review, code-request

This is my problem: this is the code I have to plot

```
LogLogPlot[{qmax[ω], q14[ω], qhalf[ω], 
q[ω], qbec[ω]}, {ω, 0.01, 100}, 
PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0.01, 0.00001}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dotted}, {Black, 
DotDashed}, Black}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, Frame -> True, 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[{"ν = 0", "ν = 0.25", "ν = 0.50", "ν = 0.75",
"ν = 1.00"}, {0.2, 0.2}]]
```

Don't worry about the named functions, instead of "qmax[ω]" you may try with $3 \sin x$ or whatever.

The point is: this is the plot that comes out:

[image]

What I don't understand is why that vertical axes appears.

I'm trying since yesterday to make the plot (the curves) to start from a new origin defined by $(0.01, 0.0001)$ without any success.

AxesOrigin seems to fail, and what I want is just to set a new origin in that point I wrote above.

I don't know if I have been clear, but in any case, let's try the command with even just ONE or TWO naive functions like $3\sin(x)$ and $1 + x^2$.

Thank you so much!

P.s. My current Mathematica version is $10$.

Comment: I assume you've tried it without the `PlotRangePadding` option and with `Axes -> False`. Could you explain why these aren't what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.01, 10},
 PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0},
 AxesStyle -> Bold,
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The vertical line is the y-axis (obscured by the fact that you specified `Frame->True`

Compare with the default setting (no frame)

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.01, 10},
 PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0},
 AxesStyle -> Bold,
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}]
```

[image]

Now, if you want the frame without any axis:

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.01, 10},
 Axes -> False,
 PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If you want "to start from a new origin" you probably want a modified `PlotRange`, for example:

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.01, 10},
 PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0},
 PlotRange -> {0.01, 10},
 AxesOrigin -> {0.1, 1},
 AxesStyle -> Bold,
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]